# pandas: difference between selecting rows with d[condition] and d.loc[condition]? (And setting values to the rows returned)

Tags: python, pandas

For example, if I have a dataframe `d` with columns `A, B, C` and I run

`d[(d.A == 2) & (d.B > 3)]`

Is there a difference between that and this:

`d.loc[(d.A == 2) & (d.B > 3)]` ?

Wondering specifically because I will be setting values to what this conditional indexing returns, and the behavior for setting values seems to change depending on whether I have the .loc or not. But I could be wrong

Comment: For filter the row no different

Comment: They should be the same. But if you want to **set** values of some certain column, say `C`, you should use `loc`: `d.loc[(d.A == 2) & (d.B > 3), 'C'] = 'something'`. Make sure you don't chain: `d.loc[(d.A == 2) & (d.B > 3)][ 'C'] = 'something'`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks! I've indeed read that I shouldn't use chaining on previous SO posts. But could you explain why `.loc` should be used when setting values (as opposed to the first syntax I pointed out that skips `.loc`)?

Comment: Basically, it boils down to the uncertainty of returning a copy vs a view when chaining indexes, even in numpy. You can find more details in [this Pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).